# AWK: redirecting script output from script to another file with dynamic name

Tags: bash, redirect, awk, gawk

I know I can redirect awk's print output to another file from within a script, like this:

```
awk '{print $0 >> "anotherfile" }' 2procfile
```

(I know that's dummy example, but it's just an example...)

But what I need is to redirect output to another file, which has a dynamic name like this

```
awk -v MYVAR"somedinamicdata" '{print $0 >> "MYWAR-SomeStaticText" }' 2procfile
```

And the outpus should be redirected to `somedinamicdata-SomeStaticText`.

I know I can do it via:

```
awk '{print $0  }' 2procfile >> "$MYVAR-somedinamicdata"
```

But the problem is that it's a bigger awk script, and I have to output to several files depending on certain conditions (and this awk script is called from another bash, and it passes some dynamic variable via the -v switch... and son on.

Is it possible anyhow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: awk -v MYVAR="somedinamicdata" '{print $0 >> (MYWAR "-SomeStaticText") }' 2procfile    doesn't that work?

Comment: You had saved my life. Post it as answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think

```
awk -v MYVAR="somedinamicdata" '{print $0 >> (MYVAR "-SomeStaticText") }' 2procfile
```

should do it. String concatenation in awk is just put one after another.