# redirecting awk output to file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, awk, tcpdump

I am working on a bash script that captures beacon frame packets (without bad fcs) and output them in a preferred format, but I am having problem redirecting the outptut to a file.

This is my command line when I am redirecting to a file called `temp`

```
tcpdump -I -i mon0 -vv 2>/dev/null|awk -F ',| ' 'BEGIN{printf "%-10s %-25s%-10s\n","OPTION NO.","ESSID(Beacon Frames)","CHANNEL NO."};$0~/Beacon/{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){if(($i~/^\([^^]+\)$/) && !($i in arr) && ($0~/CH:/) && !($0~/tsft bad-fcs/)){NR=++c;arr[$i]=1;gsub(/\(|\)/,"",$i);printf("%-10s %-25s",NR,$i);for(x=1;x<=NF;++x){if($x~/^CH:/){print $x " "$(x+1) "\tHit Ctrl+C to stop scan"}}}}}' >> temp
```

The command line above works fine in a terminal when I am not redirecting to a file (the output is  shown).  When I am redirecting to a file, I am seeing the file exist with no output.

I tried the following

1.Pipe the command line output like `tee -a temp` (to output to stdout and file)

example

```
tcpdump -I -i mon0 -vv 2>/dev/null|awk -F ',| ' 'BEGIN{printf "%-10s %-25s%-10s\n","OPTION NO.","ESSID(Beacon Frames)","CHANNEL NO."};$0~/Beacon/{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){if(($i~/^\([^^]+\)$/) && !($i in arr) && ($0~/CH:/) && !($0~/tsft bad-fcs/)){NR=++c;arr[$i]=1;gsub(/\(|\)/,"",$i);printf("%-10s %-25s",NR,$i);for(x=1;x<=NF;++x){if($x~/^CH:/){print $x " "$(x+1) "\tHit Ctrl+C to stop scan"}}}}}'|tee -a temp
```

2. I tried

   `exec > temp
   command line above`

Can this be a buffering issue since packet capturing is rapid?

How can the results of the above command line be redirected to a file?

Note: `mon0` in the command line represents the monitor interface I started on my wireless adapter using `airmon-ng`

**edit:** the breakdown of the codes are as follows

```
BEGIN {
    FS=",| "
    printf "%-10s %-25s%-10s\n","OPTION NO.","ESSID(Beacon Frames)","CHANNEL NO."
}
$0~/Beacon/ {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) {
        if(($i~/^\([^^]+\)$/) && !($i in arr) && ($0~/CH:/) && !($0~/tsft bad-fcs/)) {
            NR=++c
            arr[$i]=1
            gsub(/\(|\)/,"",$i)
            printf("%-10s %-25s",NR,$i)
            for(x=1;x<=NF;++x) {
                if($x~/^CH:/) {
                    print $x " "$(x+1) "\tHit Ctrl+C to stop scan"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As i mentioned the codes work fine..it is just the redirection issue..do offer improvements to the code if needed.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that the code doesn't suite for a one-liner? Use `awk -f script.awk` and post `script.awk` in your question - properly indented.

Comment: Yes I know..My mistake here..but the script is very large..so I tried some one-liner codes (my apologies)

Comment: Just change it. It would be probably an upvote instead of a downvote.

Comment: okay give me a second

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302152/awk-redirecting-script-output-from-script-to-another-file-with-dynamic-name?rq=1

Comment: @ hek2mgl..internet issues on my side...however i edited my answer for a clearer description of the codes....thank you

Comment: @EdMorton Nope..I have tried `tcpdump... | awk '{print}' > file`. It works fine (it redirect output to file)..

Comment: @EdMorton I like that kind of debugging :) .. You might blame me why I not use Google but are there debuggers for awk and have you used some?

Comment: I tried eliminating the codes piece by piece for hours to see what the issue was (even skipped lunch and breakfast)...`NR=++c` ...I change the records because..there are so many packets flowing out of the screen..once I find the packet that has a beacon frame, I  output the packet and a add number to it (like a numbering counter).

Comment: @EdMorton..okay I will make this correction with the counter in my script

Comment: Please, for this question, just reduce your script to the smallest possible example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of reading on awk and  gawk..I came across a very interesting topic on buffering behaviour in one of my text.This solved my problem..I changed the buffering behaviour of awk using the following

```
fflush("") ==> gawk and newer versions of awk
```

or

```
system("")==> older versions of awk
```

This forces awk to flush its output immediately for every input line.

I tried each of the aforementioned functions in  my command line and my output was immediately redirected to my file `temp`.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the answer and i haven't worked with bash in forever but possibly try sending it to a text file. temp may be treated as a directory. Instead try exec > temp.txt

Comment: No. Nothing in UNIX cares about file name extensions like `.txt`. You can name a directory `temp.txt` if you like and no UNIX tool will care.

Comment: Tried this but no result..+1 for trying to help me